# Thin stripe of view to appear on the top of selected tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabitem

I need a red stripe on top of the tab that is currently selected as shown below,

[image]

Kindly suggest on the best ways of doing it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to create a custom TabBarController for this

Comment: Either you can use selected Image like this